# Understanding React Native with callback in type

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am new to react ( native) and typescript and do not fully understand what is the correct syntax for the below example from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html Call Signature

it is working in https://www.typescriptlang.org/ but also have warnings

```
type printFunction = {
  name : string,
  (a: string) : void
}
function greeter( fn: printFunction ) {
  fn.a("Hello " + fn.name);
}

function printToConsole(s: string) {
  console.log(s);
}

greeter({name:"Henk", a:printToConsole});
```

if some one can shine some light it will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The reason why TS complains is because your object doesn't match the type definition. If you want to create an object with 2 fields (`name` and `a`) where one of the fields is a function, the type should look something like this

```
type printFunction = {
  name : string,
  a:(a: string) => void
}
```

What you have now is a type describing a function itself, so if you create an instance of it you should be calling that instance directly - `fn('something')` not `fn.a('something')`

Comment: Thanks for answering, I sort of understand what you are saying. But should the type not be: 
type printFunction = {
  name : string,
  a : (a: string) => void
}

Comment: It should indeed! as it becomes a function expression as opposed to a normal function that you had in your example. I'll fix it :)